# How to get ILoggerFactory instance in .NET 6 Program.cs class

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, iloggerfactory

In .NET 5 `ILoggerFactory` can be accessed in the Startup constructor as follows:

```
public Startup(
    IConfiguration configuration,
    IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     LoggerFactory = loggerFactory;
     Configuration = configuration;
     HostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
}
```

I just have a custom package that receives as a parameter the `ILoggerFactory` instance

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCustomMvc(Configuration, loggerFactory: LoggerFactory);
}
```

In .NET 6 how can I get the `ILoggerFactory` before the `app.Build()` like this

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddCustomMvc(configuration, loggerFactory: loggerFactory);

var app = builder.Build();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Can you change the custom MVC package? It could just resolve the ILoggerFactory from IServiceProvider like services do in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is not much options except creating `ILoggerFactory` manually (as [done](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#log-in-programcs) to log in top-level statement `Program` file):

```cs
using var loggerFactory =
    LoggerFactory.Create(lb => lb.AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration));

builder.Services.AddCustomMvc(configuration, loggerFactory: loggerFactory);
```

Which will require you to repeat the logging setup.

Other options:

- switch back to the generic hosting
- rework `AddCustomMvc` approach so there would be no need to pass the `loggerFactory` (change registrations to resolve from `IServiceProvider`)

Comment: I guess for now I will keep with the option of creating the `ILoggerFactory` as I do not want to use BuildServiceProvider to create a second dependency container just for getting the logger factory instance. Thanks!

Comment: @CamiloTorresC. Was glad to help! I have not mentioned building service provider option cause in my opinion it is a complete no-no)